# Python Master Volume Control

Tags: python, windows-10

I want to make a small program that changes the volume levels of programs based on what programs are open and possibly given audio detection, for example if im running a game window, and I have music in the background, I'd want it to lower the music volume if it detects audio being sent from the game window.

I usually play with game volumes turned off, but I usually watch cutscenes, so my goal is to have the music playing and mute if a cutscene comes up.

I dont know how doable it is with python, but I have the most knowledge of python thus Im asking for that if possible, I could do it in another language if anyone has suggestion.

So more or less, I just need some direction on what libraries of languages would be useful for making this program.

OS involved - Windows 10

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: Won't there be audio being sent from the game even without cutscenes ? I don't see how you would be able to detect the difference between game sounds and cutscene sounds.

Comment: Windows 10, should've specified that

Comment: You can mute it, but Idk if it sents the audio packages without pushing the volume through

Comment: Err you can mute the in-game sounds is what I meant, but you can keep the cutscene volume on

Comment: I wrote a library for that if you want to give it a try https://github.com/AndreMiras/pycaw